# New field not always showing while using checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and have a question regarding a list of checkboxes. I have a list of attributes (via ng-repeat) with a checkbox for each attribute. 
When I select a specific attribute (in my case one with the name TG) a new input field shows.

However when I select one of the other checkboxes (and TG remains checked) the new input field disappears again. 
I am using ng-show for the new field

**Update**

Part of the code:

```
                            <div sw-field
                                 ng-model="data.Infra"
                                 ng-show="data.Infra === 'Assignment'"
                                 data-label="Infrastructure"
                                 class="layout-column w-50"
                                 sw-direct-save="true">
                                <div sw-domain-checkboxes
                                     ng-model="data.listofcheckboxes">
                                </div>
                                <div sw-field
                                     ng-show="data.Status === 'TG'"
                                     class="w-100"
                                     sw-model="data.MaxSpeed"
                                     data-label="Speed"
                                    <input sw-edit-input ng-model="checked[data.MaxSpeed]" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: kindly showcase more of code about what you have done

Comment: I have updated the question with a part of the code

Comment: Can you add some code to this [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/F64G9/), it would make it easier to help.